# Calculating geometric mean of elach element in series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have four Series objects nSer1, nSer2, nSer3 and nSer4. How to create nSerGMean which multiplies  the series and takes the fourth root of the result.

```
nSerGMean=(nSer1*nSer2*nSer3*nSer4)^(1/4)
```

Comment: Can you add atleast 4 rows of nSer1,nSer2 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mul` and `pow` methods i.e:

```
nSerGMean = (nSer1.mul(nSer2).mul(nSer3).mul(nSer4)).pow(1/4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use numpy product along a specific dimension.

```
import numpy as np
nSerGMean = np.power(np.prod([nSer1,nSer2,nSer3,nSer4], axis = 0),0.25)
```

Optionally, you can do a log-transformation first to use summation instead.

```
nSerGMean = np.exp(
    np.mean( np.log([nSer1,nSer2,nSer3,nSer4]), axis = 0) 
    )
```